# iOS OTA Distribution "unable to download" immediately upon clicking the link

Tags: ios, ota

I have an iPad app that we are distributing over the air for QA and Beta testers; we have both a debug and and a release config that we are building. Our build process puts together the website and the PLIST manifest file that that iOS needs to install the app. The release build downloads correctly, but the debug build does not. The only difference between the two manifest files is the application that it's pointing to. I've checked server permissions, signing issues (the same app that won't install OTA can be pushed via iTunes) all to no avail.

Most of the other articles out here deal with the file nearly installing and then choking (that's typically the wrong provisioning file).

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It turns out the problem was two-fold. One of the iPads had too old of iOS, and the other was there was a hidden character in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was two-fold. One of the iPads had too old of iOS, and the other was there was a hidden character in the URL

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error before when the device has a version of iOS below the supported version of the application.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too, but our minimum version is iOS 5 and all of our iPads are on 5.0 or 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Check the url on plist file. Make sure it has correct path with http://

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible that the bundle ID is incorrect. We have multiple bundle IDs so we used to get them mixed up. In addition the icon URL is incorrect. Had that problem too